# Which is best software to mine Monero in Windows?

Tags: mining, windows

Is MinerGate a good and trusted software to mine Monero in Windows? How do they pay?

Answer (score 1):

XMRig is undoubtedly the most used and respected miner, regardless of operating system.

Minergate is widely distrusted.